# how to pop out a message window from down on update / not alert box

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a javascript code given below:

```
<script>
    setInterval(function () {
        $( "#tinq" ).load( "standard_index.php #tinq" );
    }, 12000);
</script>
```

it updates the contents perfectly after watever interval time you set. what i want is that when a query counts the value and shows in the div after a certain time, if the new value after recount is greater than previous value it should pop out a message box from down or anywhere. but not alertbox i dont want user to click ok and then go ahead. only popup a message window like we receives a new incomin email alert when we use Microsoft Outlook.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show the message only when content is greater than previous content you can check it with `jQuery('#tinq').text().length;` before and after the replacement and check if new value is greater than the other one.

```
<script>
setInterval(function () {
    var init = $( "#tinq" ).text().length;
    $( "#tinq" ).load( "standard_index.php #tinq" );
    var new = $( "#tinq" ).text().length;
    if (new > init) {
      // do something...        
    } 
}, 12000);
</script>
```

Comment: i did it but its not updating now or even i did @ // echo "do something"; its not doing anything.

Comment: You should log in console something or use alert `if (new > init) {
      console.log('big');        
}`

Comment: nothing worked.... if (new > init) { console.log('big');} i add this line in your code but nothing worked... can u please set the code for me....

Comment: thanks alot for your kind cooperation. well i have another thing that if im doing sql count query from database if the messages for a user are 4 and then again the message comes and if the total messages are equal to 5 or 6 then it popout a message " you have new inquiry please check "... can u please help about this ????